# Java not printing after Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm studying Java, and now I need to print the array printing exception messages.
But when I run the code he stops at the first exception message (a[1]) and close the program without finishing the array, what I'm doing wrong?

He should show me: a0 + error + a2 + error + a4
But he's showing: a0 + error

This is my first class:

```
package media;

public class aluno {
    
    private String nome;
    private double nota1, nota2;
    private double media;
    
    public aluno(String n, double n1, double n2) {
        this.nome = n;
        this.nota1 = n1;
        this.nota2 = n2;
    }
public double calcularMedia() {
        if (nota1 > 10 || nota2 > 10) {
              throw new ArithmeticException("Médias e notas não podem passar de 10!");
            }
           
        else if(nota1 < 0 || nota2 < 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Médias e notas devem se manter entre 0 e 10!");
        }
         else {
              media = (this.nota1 + this.nota2) / 2; 
         }
        return media;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Aluno: " + nome + " Media: " + calcularMedia();
    }

}
```

And this is my main:

```
package media;

public class program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aluno a[] = new aluno[5];
        a[0] = new aluno("Guilherme", 8, 9);
        a[1] = new aluno("Leonardo", 16, 2);
        a[2] = new aluno("Beatriz", 6, 10);
        a[3] = new aluno("Karina", -2, -5);
        a[4] = new aluno("Gustavo", 3, 8);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An uncaught exception terminates execution of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should att a try-catch block into your for loop. The main method will be stoped because the first element throws an exception which is not handled.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            try{
                System.out.println(a[i].toString());
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException ex){
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

This way the ArithmeticException will be handled for each element of the array.

In addition, the class names start with capital letter so Aluno instead of aluno.

Throwing exception will also return your function so you could simplify you code too. There is no need for the else cases. It increases the readability of your code. This kind of if conditions are called guard statements.

```java
public double calcularMedia() {
        if (nota1 > 10 || nota2 > 10) {
              throw new ArithmeticException("Médias e notas não podem passar de 10!");
        }
        if(nota1 < 0 || nota2 < 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Médias e notas devem se manter entre 0 e 10!");
        }
        return (this.nota1 + this.nota2) / 2; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after posting this I figure it was the try/catch that I forgot, but I couldn't figure out where I should insert. So I'm really glad.